# Bunyan Logger typescript configuration Errror named logger cannot be named

Tags: node.js, typescript, logging, bunyan

I am trying to configure my Bunyan Logger for NodeJS project. This configuration was working fine, until I started to convert my project to Typescript.

Here is the configuration function for configuring my loggers in the file MyLogger.ts:

```
import { createWriteStream } from 'fs'
import { stdSerializers, createLogger } from 'bunyan'
const pkg = require('../../package.json')

export default function (logLevel: string = 'debug', logFolder: string) {
  const logOptions = {
    serializers: stdSerializers,
    name: `${pkg.name}-${pkg.version}`,
    streams: [
      { level: 'error', stream: process.stderr },
      { level: logLevel, stream: process.stdout }
    ]
  }

  if (logFolder) {
    logOptions.streams.push(
      { level: logLevel, stream: createWriteStream(`${logFolder}/${pkg.name}.log`) })
  }

  const logger = createLogger ({
    name: logOptions.name,
    streams: logOptions.streams
  })

  return logger
}
```

now when I compile the typescript, I get the following error:

> lib/config/MyLogger.ts(5,1): error TS4058: Return type of exported
>   function has or is using name 'Logger' from external module
>   "project-folder/node_modules/@types/bunyan/index"
>   but cannot be named.

I am using node version: 6.9.2
Bunyan version: 1.8.5
@types/bunyan": "0.0.35

Any help understanding the error or how to solve this.. would be great.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on the typescript issue here: [TS4023](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5711)

I got the compilation running by adding an import as:

```
import * as Logger from '@types/bunyan'
```

and then addding a return type to my exported function as `Logger`.